# Codeigniter form validation library

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, validation

I am using the form validation library however I have come across something I cannot work out how to do.

I have several fields,

I have:

- page_title => required
- menu_title => not required
- parent_id => null or required

Now if menu_title is not set then it should take on the value of page_title.
Then, I need to do a check to make sure that, at the given level the menu_title is unique.

So,

```
if($menu_title == '')
    $menu_title = $page_title;

return $this->db->
select('menu_title')->
from('cart_categories')->
where(array('menu_title' => $menu_title,
            'parent_id' => $category_parent))->
get()->num_rows() == 0;
```

But I don't know how to actually use that in the form validation library?

Comment: Where did you set up your validation rules, or did you get that far?

Comment: Yeah, I have the start of the validation rules when the form is submitted, e.g. I have the page_title required check and an exists callback running on the parent_id, it's just the more complicated part that I don't get.

Comment: I could technically use a callback function and inside the function access the other two variables via `$this->input->post('whatever')` but that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Well, yeah, you will need to set up your own callback function (e.g `$this->form_validation->set_rules('menu_title', 'Menu Title', my_callback_function);` , and evaluate the query result in the function. See [the docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) for an example of how to write it, ctrl-f and look for `Callbacks`.

Comment: Yeah, I am using a callback to ensure that parent_id actually exists, and I was guessing that I will use a callback for the menu_title, I guess what I am most curious about is how I would a) pass the multiple parameters through to the callback, or should I just access them using the post results directly?

Comment: The callback is definitely the way to go, but it's only going to get one argument. You could just set class variables to hold that to give the callback convenient access to them, or get them right from `$this->input->post()` from within the callback. Matter of preference I suppose. But since the string is passed _anyway_ you may as well make use of it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking, it just doesn't seem very clean, but meh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a callback function in order to do that. Just define one (changed code around slightly to fit formatting). Note, this is off the top of my head (and the docs):

```
public function check_title($string) {
    $this->db->select('menu_title')->from('cart_categories');
    $this->db->where(array('menu_title' => $string,'parent_id' => $this->input->post('category_parent')));
    if ($this->db->get()->num_rows() != 0 {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_title', '%s must be unique');
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Then set the input for that particular field to use the callback:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('menu_title', 'Menu Title', 'callback_check_title');
```

I *think* you can add an additional underscore to the left side of the callback function name to make sure CI does not route it (as it is public), and just reflect that where you enter the callback name to the rules. I'm not positive about that, though.

As far as passing the additional field as the callback only takes the string, you could just set a class variable.

You can also just handle the validation yourself, which might be cleaner in your case.